How to make an effective site search?
I'm trying to implement a site search that is actually usable by real people who don't put exact terms in the search bar, sometimes makes spelling mistakes and so forth.
Here's one example. I have a list of hotels in a database and want to search them by name. The name of one of the hotel is "Taj Wellington Mews Mumbai". The expected search term for it is "taj mumbai".
Here's what I've tried:

When using LIKE the search term doesn't match the name at all.
I created a Fulltext index and tried Match() Against() it returns any hotel that contains the words "taj" or "mumbai" like "The St Regis Mumbai".
I split the query into words and removed certain words, added a + in front of each word, so to force the database to include each word.

$q = sanitize($_POST['search']);
$qParts = explode(' ', $q);
$fullTextQuery = '';
$filterWords = [
    'the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'and', 'a', 'an'
];
foreach ($qParts as $key) {
    if(in_array(strtolower($key), $filterWords))
        return;
    $fullTextQuery .= '+'.$key.' ';
}
$searchQuery = "SELECT name, link FROM hotels WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('$fullTextQuery' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status = 2";

Problem is that now this kind of search term doesn't work "taj mum". The user will have to complete the word 'mumbai' to get the results.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

"When using LIKE the search term doesn't match the name at all." - no, not if you search with LIKE '%taj mumbai%', of course - because your column does not contain taj mumbai. But if you search with LIKE '%taj%mumbai%', to alloy any arbitrary content in between those two words as well ...

But then of course you still would not find that record, if the user typed in mumbai taj instead. You could create a LIKE comparison in that order as well, of course - but with more than two search terms, that would quickly lead to an enormous number of possible combinations.

Try to append an asterisk for each word, you should query for +taj* +mum*.

But you can do something like select (name like '%taj%') + (name like '%Mumbai%') as matchCount from table HAVING matchCount = 2 - then the order in which each of those individual words was found, doesn't matter. The number in the HAVING clause needs to match your number of search terms.

My primary concern is how will you know which one to look for and which one to ignore? Of course, Taj and Mumbai are well known places in this example, but unless you are keeping an enormous database of every hotel and city in the world, what's your logic to determine which one to search and which one to discard, as there are names which are not part of English vocabulary, stop-word elimination won't be much effective.

Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

Why the downvotes?
@shingo Your suggestion is the best. It eliminates the drawback mentioned in point 3. Mind putting it down as the answer?
@C3roe That's a nice tip, I didn't know LIKE could be used like that but I think I'll still go with Fulltext because of the drawback you mentioned yourself. Thank though.

@Dharman I'm not "wide open" to SQL injections. Prepared statements would be marginally safer but I'm alright. I've challenged many like you - always preaching prepared statements - to actually do an SQL injection, none have succeeded.

Why? Why are you against prepared statements? They are easier, faster and safer to use. Also, judging by the fact that you have a method sanitize() and no escaping in the SQL query, I am going to have to respectfully say you have no idea what you are advocating for.

The downvotes are most likely for posting code open to SQL injection.

I'm not against prepared statements at all and I use them myself but not everywhere. Also the sanitize function contains mysqli_real_escape_string in addition to some extra measures. That was not the point of this question at all. Off topic comments should be downvoted too. I'm annoyed by prepared statements warriors jumping in with their opinions everywhere.

Related to your point 2. FULLTEXT search ordinarily returns more results than the desired one, and relies on the person using it to choose the desired one. It attempts to order its results usefully, and sometimes  succeeds. It has limited functionality. Algolia? Apache Solr?

@Whip That code is not safe from SQL injections, end of statement. mysqli_real_escape_string is not sufficient and people don't assume that you have took "extra measures", and they really shouldn't have to. Prepared statements are necessary and the ideal way to protect from SQLi as they don't have any drawbacks, nor any limitations. There's really no reason one shouldn't be using them, ever. They aren't a matter of "opinion" and have never been so amongst those who code in PHP.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

@SyedM.Sannan I'll repeat, this question is not remotely about sql injections or preventions. Secondly, the top voted answer from your link says 'If you use a modern SQL server and don't use a vulnerable character set, You are 100% safe'

@Whip It doesn't have to be. People point out vulnerabilities for future visitors so that they don't blindly copy/paste vulnerable code. StackOverflow isn't just about helping the questioner. The questions and the answers are both, in fact, only means towards the primary goal, and that is to help future visitors who see posts on here. If a post isn't helpful for future visitors, or even harms their code in any manner, then I would argue if that post even suits StackOverflow.

@Whip And lastly, once again, people don't assume that you have the right measures in place and are using the right encoding. People see vulnerable code as is, and they point it out, as they should. mysql_real_escape_string is largely known as vulnerable code and it's extra precautions, usually not even part of the code itself, that don't make it as such. When I see it, I would assume that the code is not secure as I should so that future readers would be alarmed copying it into their codebases with potentially not the same measures taken.

Also, please check the improved answer on that page regarding the issue (especially the "Wrapping Up" section): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23277864/13349935 . Top-voted doesn't necessarily mean the best.

You can use Tags for search and over time you will train your search, first you put in your database the popular tags for every Hotel for your instance "Taj Wellington Mews Mumbai" with tags [taj, mumbai, wellington, mews, mum, welling,...etc.], Then you will need a score for every row (Hotel) to each tag. Imagine that your visitor typed (taj mum) then clicked on "Taj Wellington Mews Mumbai" then you will add +1 point for this tag associated with this row (Hotel). It will be better over time and more accurate (not so accurate of course).
